# Python: asynchronously process tasks that are results from other asynchronous tasks

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am trying to fetch data of all *transactions* for several *addresses* from an API. Each address can have several pages of transactions, which I find out only when I ask for first page.

I have methods `api.get_address_data(address, page)` and `api.get_transaction_data(tx)`.

Synchronous code for what I want to do would look like this:

```py
def all_transaction_data(addresses):
    for address in addresses:
        data = api.get_address_data(address, page=0)
        transactions = data.transactions
        for n in range(1, data.total_pages):
            next_page = api.get_address_data(address, page=n)
            transactions += next_page.transactions
        for tx in data.transactions:
            yield api.get_transaction_data(tx)
```

I don't care about the order of transactions received (I will have to reorder them when I have all of them ready). I can fit all the data in memory, but it's a lot of very little requests, so I'd like to do as much in parallel as possible.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I was playing around with asyncio (the API calls are under my control so I can convert them to `async`), but I have trouble with interleaving the layers: my best solution can fetch all the addresses first, list all the pages second and finally get all transactions in one big batch. I would like each processing step to be scheduled immediately when the appropriate input data is ready, and the results collected into one big list (or yielded from a single generator).

It seems that I need some sort of open-ended task queue, where task "get-address" fetches the data and enqueues a bunch of "get-pages" tasks, which in turn enqueue "get-transaction" tasks, and only these are then collected into a list of results?

Can this be done with asyncio? Would something like gevent be more suitable, or maybe just a plain ThreadPoolExecutor? Is there a better approach than what I outlined so far?

Note that I'd like to avoid inversion of control flow, or at least hide it as an implementation detail. I.e., the caller of this code should be able to just call `for tx in all_transaction_data()`, or at worst `async for`.